Golang test not executing defer statement when timing out
I have noticed that go tests do not execute defer or t.Cleanup statements when running past the default 10m timeout (or otherwise specified using the -timeout flag).
Consider the following code:
package timeout_test

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func TestTimeoutDeferCleanup(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("This is printed.")
    defer fmt.Println("This is not printed.")
    t.Cleanup(func() {
        fmt.Println("This is not printed either.")
    })
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
}

Run this with go test -v -timeout 1s ./timeout_test.go.
Does anyone know a way around this other than disabling the timer (-timeout 0)?

You can't interrupt a goroutine. When the test times out, the only thing it can do is panic to kill the test process which isn't going to execute anything else in the tests

The test timeout is a failsafe to ensure the test process terminates at some point, not part of the tests. If you need some logic around timeouts, make your tests timeout themselves.

You expect your tests to exit after the timeout, and “the program would not exit” would be clearly a problem on your CI. Otherwise you would need another task to kill the go test process, again resulting in the messages not printed.
So why are the side effects (message printing) not executed before exiting the program?
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go func() {
        defer fmt.Println("This is not printed either.")
        fmt.Println("This is most likely printed.")
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("This is not printed.")
    }()
    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
}

On an average desktop machine this exits after 100 milliseconds, abandoning the running goroutine:

It does not wait for other (non-main) goroutines to complete.

Waiting for all goroutines to finish would mean exit could not be deterministic and a faulty goroutine would delay exit forever.
Everything else (like speeding up timers) would be surprising, because side effects would happen too early and still not guarantee the program to exit.
Abandoning background tasks is handled in a similar way as in other languages, i.e. Java.
So why not at least call the “cleanup” functions? When you interrupt program flow in the middle of execution you are in an inconsistent state and can only exit. Everything else would be “inherently unsafe”.
You view your side effects as harmless, they are just printing text. But where to stop? Is unlocking mutexes okay? Is some operation that closes a channel and shortly locks a mutex still fine?
Note that the output of the above program is non-deterministic. It has one output that is very likely on fast enough machines, but might print all lines or nothing at all in unusual circumstances.
